# Make input number value selected after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is possible to make selected input number value selected after page refresh?

for example, I am selecting the 5 number from this field, and than i am refreshing the page, after this my selected number 5 should be there as selected.

I searched on internet and try many code but not worked, I try the below code.

```
<input autocomplete="on" onkeyup='saveValue(this);' type="number" name="pro_qty" id="pro_qty" class="form-control qty" required>

</script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var a = sessionStorage.getItem('pro_qty');
        if(a !== null){ 
            //alert(a);
            document.getElementById("pro_qty").value = a; 
        }
    }

    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        sessionStorage.setItem("pro_qty", $('#pro_qty').val());
    }
</script>
```

I am working on big project with multiple add number field functionally and i am stopped because of this problem, In my case page is refresh with ajax and number field is disappeared. Is there any solution?

Comment: why your ajax is refreshing the page?

Comment: I am fetching the data from selected id and transferring it to another page using ajax, I am using codeigniter for that, I think page is refresh in background

Answer (score 3):

try below code,

```
var varName = "value";
localStorage.setItem("someVarName", varName );
var someVarName = localStorage.getItem("someVarName");
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you use Local Storage? The value will be available even after you refresh the page.

Comment: I don't know how to use local storage for that?

Comment: Below is the working example :                                                        <script>
    window.onload = function()
    {
        var a = localStorage.getItem('num');
        if(a !== null){ 
            //alert(a);
            document.getElementById("pro_qty").value = a; 
        }
    }

    function saveValue(s){
    if(!b){
     var b = localStorage.setItem('num',document.getElementById('pro_qty').value);
}
else{
     b = localStorage.setItem('num',document.getElementById('pro_qty').value);
}
}
</script>

Comment: This link has complete example : https://plnkr.co/edit/b10pbJIhgxtlJu6HznV8?p=preview